# Using slotRenderEndedEvent to refresh slots, but it doesn't fire when got unsold

Tags: addeventlistener, google-ad-manager, google-publisher-tag

I got some code, where i got event listener for `googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotRenderEnded", function(event){})`
, it works ok but doesn't fire when there's no creative comes from google server. Is there any way to fire when there's no creative?

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener("slotRenderEnded", function(event){
    var slotId = event.slot.getSlotId().getId();
    if(checkSlot(slotId))
    {
        refreshTimeout(event.slot);
    }
});
```

Maybe there's other event that i could use instead of slotRenderEndedEvent?

Comment: according to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.events.SlotRenderEndedEvent) : "This event is fired when the creative code is injected into a slot". If no creative is displayed, the event will not be fired. But most importantly : why would you refresh an emtpty slot ? If ad manager didn't select any line item, it means it doesn't have any ad to display. If you force the slot to refresh : it will be empty again... and again... and again...

Comment: you might want to test the [slotResponseReceived](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletageventsslotresponsereceived) event...